# File input : Chrome is not checking if file still exist before submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I recently found a bug that made my server crash during a file upload.

When the user clicks on a file input, and chooses a file to upload. If the user deletes or renames the file before submitting the form, Chrome still sends an empty file. (while firefox and IE handle the error correctly)

After the user has clicked on the "submit" button, I've tryed to check the file size, but it is not null.

```
        if (file.size == 0) {
            NotificationFactory.AlertMessage({ messageType: "error", message: "File is missing" });
        }
```

I've already handled the error server-side, but would like to add some validation client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the JavaScript [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) we can pull the size of the file through the object's [`size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-size) using `element.files[0].size`. To ensure that a file exists with JavaScript, we can simply:

```js
if(typeof el.files[0] !== 'undefined' && el.files[0].size > 0) {
    /* Success! */
}
```

We use `typeof` to ensure that a file has actually been selected (`el.files[0]` will be *undefined* otherwise), and then if that passes we check that the file size is greater than 0.

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/U5tjR/1) which I've tested in Chrome.

As an important note, however, you would still need some server-side validation for users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. As I said, I already validated it server-side